Why is Local Override for Response Headers (e.g. Chrome Devtools) not applied to Pre-Fetch OPTIONS Response Headers?
Was trying to fix some of my local dev setup today and didn't want to fuss about with server configs just to make CORS work locally - so finally delved into just overriding headers when developing on localhost. For reference, the way to do it in Chrome is explained in https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides. However, after painstaking trial and error, I discovered that it only works on non pre-flighted requests, i.e. simple requests (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).
Requests that are designated as "pre-flight" do not have the overrides applied to the OPTIONS response headers and therefore the entire request fails.
This limitation (?) is not mentioned in https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides#limitations. Is this limitation explained anywhere or perhaps I am missing some critical understanding - it makes no sense why overrides would be selectively applied on parts of responses.
